# What is an apomorphy? What is a plesiomorphy? Can someone confirm these definitions?

Tags: cladistics

I want to know the correct definitions for the terms *apomorphy* and *plesiomorphy*. Unfortunately, there seems to be a variety of ways to define these terms depending on the language one uses. Thus, it has been hard to determine the correct definitions. I have settled on definitions that seem correct to me and also have examples. I would like confirmation from someone if I am understanding the definitions correctly.

- **Apomorphy** -- any character state or trait novel to a species and its descendants. An apomorphy occurs when a taxon is selected to have a particular trait. **Example:** within the class reptilia, the suborder serpentes (snakes) has an apomorphy because its members have no legs.
- **Plesiomorphy** -- an evolutionary trait or character state that is homologous within a particular taxon but is not unique to members of that group and therefore cannot be used as a diagnostic character for the group. **Example:** within the class reptilia, legs are a plesiomorphy for its members.

**My Question:**

Are these definitions and examples accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds pretty good. On this kind of things wikipaedia is very reliable.
You can also look at this very synthetic page:

https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/distinguish-between-synapomorphy-apomorphy-304128

Comment: The link has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Apomorphy can simply be defined as **derived trait or character state** that is distinct to a particular species or group in a phylogenetic tree down to its descendants. The example you cited is fine.

Plesiomorphy is an **ancestral** or primitive traits that are homologous to a certain group of organisms but not unique to the other members of the group, hence cannot be used as a diagnostic character for the group.

Comment: Please try adding citation or scientific references to your answer.